# Filtering LookupMulti by FilterMultiValue SP2010

Tags: lookup-column, filter

I can't filter LookupMulti's column using FilterMultiValue. My Url contain this fragment

```
FilterName=Tags&FilterMultiValue=Flower;Sword
```

Three is nothing, apart correlation ID. I found in UlsViewer

> Unable to execute query: Error 0x80131904

and this

> Unknown SQL Exception 156 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Comment: I found that filtering LookUpMulti by few values is imposible

Comment: As I know, the URL can't use to filter with column Lookup and Allow Multi value.